# APIs to get most downloaded Files details from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We need to track the count of File Downloaded through Google Analytics.

We found that, through below code we can track the file download :

```
<a href="pdfs/my-file.pdf" onclick="var that=this;_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','PDF',this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">Download my file</a>
```

This works fine.
But, in our website we want to show most downloaded(top 5) files in a specific section.

So, can anyone suggest that is such API available in Google Analytics to retrive top N number of downloads? Or should we go with the Custom tracking implementation to achieve this feature?

Thanks in advance,

Ashish Shukla

Comment: Can't you just look up events triggered by page?

Comment: Hi Vly, 
Thanks for your quick response. 
Are you telling about the tracking click event through Jquery/Javascript and asynchronously increase count in our database for particular file?

Comment: Sorry, I am not following.
The snippet you posted contains onclick functionality that pushes Events into you GA account (assuming your page contains the GA tracker). This data can be found under standard reports/content/events/top events

Comment: As vly states, the data should be populating into your google accounts.   Can you verify this?  It seems your question is more about creating a widget of sorts to display on your webpage the top 5 downloads.  Correct?

Comment: Thanks vly and M Schenkel. Sorry for a late reply.

I did some R&D and found that by using oAuth API of Google Analytics we can get analytics data. 
But, we want to show this statistics to public visitors, the authentication is not a good idea.

So, my question is that can we create any widget or through any API can we show top most 5 downloads statistics to our site Visitors?